# Suppose $c: I \rightarrow O(n)$ is a smooth curve with $c(0) = \text{Id}_n$. Prove that $c'(0)$ is skew-adjoint.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Suppose $c: I \rightarrow O(n)$ is a smooth curve with $c(0) = \text{Id}_n$, where $\text{Id}_n$ is the nxn identity matrix, and $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, and $O(n)$ is the set of orthogonal $n$x$n$ matrices.

Prove that $c'(0)$ is skew-adjoint, i.e. $c'(0) + c'(0)^T = \mathbf{0}$.

All I can think of is some relations from physics between dot products of vector functions and their derivatives.

Comment: Can you express the fact $c(t) \in O(n)$ as an equation? Differentiate it at $t=0.$

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Yeah, just $<c(t)v_1, c(t)v_2> = <v_1, v_2>$ and $c(t)^T = c(t)^{-1}$. Neither of these equations can be simply differentiated.

Comment: How about ${}^\intercal c(t)c(t)=I_n$? Recalling that the matrix product is bilinear.

Comment: Use Taylor Formula : $c(t)= Id+ tA+o(t)$, then the equation $c.c^T=Id$ yields $Id+t(A+A^T)+o(t)=Id$